# How can I remove or delete my Arqade/stack-exchange account?

Tags: support, user-accounts

How can I remove or delete my Arqade/stack-exchange account?

I made it using my Facebook name so I can up vote a very helpful comment. Only to learn I need 15 points first, which I'm not willing to do.